# How to pass AES String crypted through HTTP header using javax.crypto

Tags: java, encryption

In one of our internal software we're implementing a new API endpoint which must be accessed by external sources through the internet and then it must be secured in some way.

Since we're not allowed to use library as `OAuth` or public and private keys we choosed javax.crypto `AES` to crypt out a "custom authorisation token" in each external source by this way:

```
...
Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec("API-KEY".getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
byte[] applicationIdEncrypted = cipher.doFinal(applicationId.getBytes());
...
```

The `token` contains a custom `applicationId` to identify on the other side who's contacting that endpoint.

Since we must perform an HTTP call, we're converting `applicationIdEncrypted`  into a base64 String

```
String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(applicationIdEncrypted);
```

**ON THE OTHER SIDE**

We're getting the header and decode it from base64

```
String base64Decoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(header));
```

But when attempting to perform the last operation

```
Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec("API-KEY".getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);

String headerDecoded = new String(cipher.doFinal(base64Decoded.getBytes())); //<- THIS
```

We got `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`

Both `base64Encoded` and `base64Decoded` have the same value in both of the ends.

**Attempting to perform the same operation in one of the ends** (to not use the HTTP channel) no exception is thrown -but- a different `headerDecoded` is returned by the `new String(cipher.doFinal(base64Decoded.getBytes()));`

Looked for the bytes `applicationIdEncrypted` and `base64Decoded.getBytes()` and they're slightly different:

**applicationIdEncrypted**

```
[-28, -103, 107, 70, -112, 121, 4, -14, -80, -114, -14, 92, -81, -13, -128, 97]
```

**base64Decoded.getBytes()**

```
[-28, -103, 107, 70,   63, 121, 4, -14, -80, -114, -14, 92, -81, -13, -128, 97]
```

I read that maybe passing from bytes to String could be a loss of informations (maybe?) but I cannot figure it out why of this behaviours since both `base64Encoded` and `base64Decoded` have the SAME value in both cases and scenarios.

How can I achieve the passage of a "custom authorisation token" using only Java 1.7 `javax.crypto` libraries?

EDIT

The `"API-KEY"` is something like `02E30E6BE24BF1EA`

Comment: Several anti-patterns are used here but I think the problem is confusion between bytes and characters. This line `String base64Decoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(header));` seems incorrect, since the `header`, when decoded, is the result of an encryption and not a String. This step will cause information to be lost, effectively corrupting the data.

Comment: Yeah... I know that's quite aberrant code but this is my first time and I'm a completely newbie but you managed to give me the correct input for the solution. I'll post it now. Thankyou!

Comment: For some background why `String` is not a good way to handle arbitrary binary data see [the javadoc for Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html). Ciphertext for any modern cipher, including but not limited to AES, is arbitrary binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @James K Polk says, I had a mess with the thousand of `String` conversion so I managed to have a cleaner code first for a better comprehensive code.

**ON THE CLIENT**

```
Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec("API-KEY".getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);

byte[] applicationIdEncrypted = cipher.doFinal(applicationId.getBytes());
byte[] base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(applicationIdEncrypted);

String out = new String(base64Encoded);
```

where `out` is the only one conversion in `String` and it's the HTTP header's payload.

**ON THE OTHER SIDE**

```
byte[] in = out.getBytes();
byte[] base64Decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(in);

Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec("API-KEY".getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
byte[] applicationIdDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(base64Decoded);

String applicationId= new String(applicationIdDecrypted);
```

I had ONLY two conversion into `String`: `out` (the header's base64 value) and  `applicationId`.

In this way I used to have the same `applicationId` value.

Comment: Two other points. 1) Always specify the full `algorithm/mode/padding` string to `Cipher.getInstance()`. The way you're doing it now is not portable and has no advantages. 2) Always specify the `Charset` argument to `String.getBytes()` and always use the String constructor with a Charset argument. Again, this is because you sacrifice portability and gain no advantages by omitting the Charset. In almost every case the UTF_8 charset is optimal choice.

Comment: @James K Polk Many thanks for your advices! I'll update this answer with the new code version asap. Thankyou again!